# datatable js with keytable when get data from server

Tags: jquery, datatables

can not make datakey js work with datatable js when the data come from server

it's work when the data is html but when move to get data from server

not work at all

```
var table = $('#' + attrs.id).dataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": false,
      "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
      "bDestroy": true,
      "aoColumns": [
      { "mDataProp": ["a"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["b"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["c"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["d"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["e"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["f"] }
      ],
      "sAjaxSource": '/api/phases',

    });

    var keys = new KeyTable({
      "table": document.getElementById(attrs.id),
      "initScroll": false
    });


    $('#' + attrs.id + ' tbody td').each(function () {
          keys.event.action(this, function (nCell) {
            /* Block KeyTable from performing any events while jEditable is in edit mode */
            keys.block = true;
            /* Initialise the Editable instance for this table */
            $(nCell).editable(function (sVal, x) {
              var aPos = table.fnGetPosition(this);
              table.fnUpdate(sVal, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
              keys.block = false;
              return sVal;
            }, {
              "indicator": 'Saving...',
              "tooltip": 'Click to edit...',
              "onblur": 'submit',
              "onreset": function () {
                /* Unblock KeyTable, but only after this 'esc' key event has finished. Otherwise
                 * it will 'esc' KeyTable as well
                 */
                setTimeout(function () { keys.block = false; }, 0);
              }
            });

            /* Dispatch click event to go into edit mode */
            setTimeout(function () { $(nCell).click(); }, 0);
          });
        });
```

why not move to edit mode when press enter on cell

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just integrate keytable after fnInitComplete

that should work well

```
var table = $('#' + attrs.id).dataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": false,
      "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
      "bDestroy": true,
      "aoColumns": [
      { "mDataProp": ["a"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["b"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["c"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["d"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["e"] },
      { "mDataProp": ["f"] }
      ],
      "sAjaxSource": '/api/phases',
      "fnInitComplete": function () {
        /* Apply a return key event to each cell in the table */
        $('#' + attrs.id + ' tbody td').each(function () {
          console.log(this);
          keys.event.action(this, function (nCell) {
            /* Block KeyTable from performing any events while jEditable is in edit mode */
            keys.block = true;
            /* Initialise the Editable instance for this table */
            $(nCell).editable(function (sVal, x) {
              var aPos = table.fnGetPosition(this);
              table.fnUpdate(sVal, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
              keys.block = false;
              return sVal;
            }, {
              "indicator": 'Saving...',
              "tooltip": 'Click to edit...',
              "onblur": 'submit',
              "onreset": function () {
                /* Unblock KeyTable, but only after this 'esc' key event has finished. Otherwise
                 * it will 'esc' KeyTable as well
                 */
                setTimeout(function () { keys.block = false; }, 0);
              }
            });

            /* Dispatch click event to go into edit mode */
            setTimeout(function () { $(nCell).click(); }, 0);
          });
        });
      }
    });

    var keys = new KeyTable({
      "table": document.getElementById(attrs.id),
      "initScroll": false
    });
```